# Is chlorophenylmethane the correct IUPAC name rather than chloromethylbenzene?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

I thought that the correct IUPAC name for the molecule below ([benzyl chloride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benzyl_chloride)) would be chloromethylbenzene because the ring always gets priority over the chain unless a primary functional group is present. However, it seems the correct name is chlorophenylmethane. Can someone explain why that is?

[image: chloromethylbenzene or chlorophenylmethane?]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The preferred IUPAC name is, indeed, *(chloromethyl)benzene*, built from substitutive prefix *chloromethyl*. The parentheses around "chloromethyl" are required because it is a compound substituent (a simple substituent attached to another simple substituent, specifically, methyl and chloro in this case). The *Blue Book* [1, p. 66] has plenty of examples similar to yours:

> $$
> \begin{array}{lll}
> \ce{C6H5-CH2-NCS} &\quad &\text{benzyl isothiocyanate} \\
>   & &\text{(isothiocyanatomethyl)benzene (PIN)} \\
>   & & \\
> \ce{C6H5-NC} &\quad &\text{phenyl isocyanide} \\
>   & &\text{isocyanobenzene (PIN)}
> \end{array}
> $$

Note that common names for this molecule also include: benzyl chloride and α-chlorotoluene.

#### References

1. Favre, H. A.; Powell, W. H. IUPAC “Blue Book” Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry: IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names; IUPAC Recommendations; *Royal Society of Chemistry: Cambridge, England*, **2013**. ISBN 978-0-85404-182-4.

Comment: The remark about the use of parentheses is correct. However, the actual question was whether the preferred name is chloro(phenyl)methane or (chloromethyl)benzene.

Comment: @Loong You are right. I was (and still am) too lazy to look up the relevant rules so just decided to edit in a brief line about the parentheses; I leave it to you if you want to expand further or write another answer.

Comment: Is 1-phenyl methyl chloride possible?